# Trying to convert "yy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss" (stored as char) into datetime using computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns

This seems like it should be simple but it's driving me up the wall.

I have two columns - 'tx_date' and 'time' stored each as char(10).  (bad database design I know, but wasn't my design)

From a query I can convert them into a datetime just fine -

"...convert(datetime,tx_date,time,11)..."

(so tx_date "09/11/27" and time "07:12:18" will produce "2009-11-27 07:12:18.000")

But if I then copy and paste the convert into the 'formula' field in SQL Server Management Studio (the same place I tested it works in a query) it tells me "Error validating the formula for column.."

If I force it to use that formula anyway it works,  but I don't want to go ahead and add this computed column to an important table until I know why it has a problem with the formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the computed field to the table in SQL Server Management Studio using a query no problem:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
  ADD NewDateTimeField AS CONVERT(DATETIME, tx_date + ' ' + time, 11)
```

but unfortunately, you cannot make it "PERSISTED" since the CONVERT function in non-deterministic. This means it'll be examined each time it's accessed, and you cannot put an index on it :-(

Marc

Comment: I don't need it to be persisted (in fact I don't want it to be because I don't want to grow the database).  I was trying to add it as a non persistent column (the 'persist' check box unchecked)

It's just for convenience really - fed up of pasting data into excel and having it think the date is the 9th of november 2027.

Comment: and... won't that alter table query just add a new standard column with the computed value actually stored there?  It needs to be computed on the fly.  (because the data essentially exists elsewhere in the table so I don't want to duplicate data unnecesarily

Comment: As long as you don't have the PERSISTED on it, it's just computed on the fly as needed - it's **NOT** stored anywhere (just the formula is - no values are stored)

Comment: Ok I went ahead and did it.  Seems to have worked fine.  Thanks Marc!